# Table column responsive arrangement with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I have a table with one row and two columns--the thing is I would like the columns to stack on top of each other for small screens. Does anyone know if this is possible using pure CSS?

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i have same doubt? if any one knows please give the solution

Answer (score 1):

How about using `float: left` solution:

```
tr td {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

tr {
    clear: left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FCegx/